# Cheapest way to ship luggage from Sweden to Germany

Tags: luggage, shipping

I was a student in Sweden and moved to Germany recently. I want to ship some of my stuff from Sweden to Germany (around 15 kilos). Companies like DHL charge exorbitant prices. I came across sendmybag.com which charges around 80 Euros. If anyone knows cheaper options than that please post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ecoparcel](http://bit.ly/1wcBOtc) has good rates, they use different couriers to deliver but you can track the package from their site.

I used the service several times, you need to load the amount in your account before order the shipment, but you can choose how much you want to load (no fixed amounts).